# How to count a specific value in a matrix

Tags: python, matrix

How to count a specific value in a matrix
I have a ready-made matrix for example 2x2 and I pass a specific value to an initialized matrix
And it returns how many times there is a certain value

```
def how_many(mat,number):
    return mat.count(number)

print(how_many(matrix(2), 2))
```

for example to matrix with 2,1,2,2 and value specific 2
Should be return 3

Comment: Is this for an saignement?

Comment: no its for task